# TryParseExact on UK date still returning USA dates

Tags: c#, date, tryparse

I have a problem in that in a live environment, my TryParseExact to convert a UK date is returning a US format date.

If I enter "01-08-2014" (1st Aug), the date variable returned is actually 8th Jan 2014 - and I cannot see why this is only in a live environment.

My conversion code is as follows:

```
    public static DateTime ToDate(object readField)
    {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.MinValue;
        if ((readField != null))
        {
            readField = readField.ToString().Replace("/", "-");
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo ukCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(readField.ToString(), new string[] { "dd-MM-yy hh:mm:ss", "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss", "dd-MM-yyyy", "d-M-yyyy", "d-M-yyyy h:mm:ss tt", "d-M-yyyy H:mm", "d-M-yyyy hh:mm tt" }, ukCulture.DateTimeFormat  , System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))                {
                return dt;
            }

        }
        return dt;
    }
```

As I say, if I pass in "01-08-2014" and then display the returning values in live...

dt.Day = 08

dt.Month = 01

On my dev machine and in the test machines, its all fine.   As far as I can tell, the settings of all the machines (langauges, date formats in control panel) are the same.  Any ideas?

Updated with the calling code and results....

The routine is being called (in this example), passing in the direct entry from an ASP Textbox as follows:

```
    if (txtSearchEndDate.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        dtSearchEndDate = LARDRHelper.ToDate(txtSearchEndDate.Text);
        txtSearchEndDate.Text = "d=" + dtSearchEndDate.Day.ToString() + " m-" + dtSearchEndDate.Month.ToString();
        storequery[2] = txtSearchEndDate.Text;
    }
```

You will see my Testline - replacing the Textbox date with the date and month..

An entry in the textbox of "01-08-2014" on my dev machine results in "d=1 m-8"

On the live box, it changes my date entry (in the text box) from "01-08-2014" to now show "d=8 m-1".

Comment: What is the datatype of readField? Why do you need to convert it to a string? Are you sure that, after the conversion, you have "01-08-2014"?

Comment: Updated with the full procedure code - its coming in as a string in format "DD-MM-YYYY" to come out as a date - but as I say, the day and month in the date have been swapped around.

Comment: @JaffaBrown: That method looks sound. I'd triple check exactly what is being passed in and fetched out. If I pass "01-08-2014" into that method I get 1st August out of it. I can't see any way that it could fail which leads me to believe either the input is not what you expect or the output is not what you are seeing, most likely the former. How are you verifying the input? Are you verifying it at the point it enters the method or are you looking at what is in the database or at some other point remote from this method?

Comment: Yep - thats why I am posting it here - I cant work it out either.  I have updated the post again with how I am calling it, how I am testing it (update textbox in my aspnet with the reseults) and the differences shown on live and test

Comment: This should work, see this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2oDjLA) - the server is running in the US but, using your method, parses the date as UK format. As you can see the resultant dates are accurate per culture, this suggests that your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: I suspect that (object readField) is null so it bypasses your TryParseExact and just returns dt. (in the 'live environment'; response.write(readField) out to the page and check it)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to James - I traced it back - it was nothing to do with the above code which worked, it was the variable holding the external date "dtSearchEndDate".   Specifically, the variable was defined as a DateTime, with a Get/Set from itself and/or viewstate - which in turn also called the date validation routine.

The problem was that in the Set, the logic was "Viewstate["dtSearchEndDate"] = value;" which saved it in the presented DATE format, which happened to be in US format - so just needed to change this to:

Viewstate["dtSearchEndDate"] = value.Tostring("dd-MM-yyyy");

This then saved it in viewstate in UK format, which then worked in the next get call.